# I get unknown error when using the goto function of watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I am running this code:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
browser.goto('example.com')
puts browser.html
```

and I get this error:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"27739.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

the error is generated by the browser.goto('example.com') instruction, because if I run

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
sleep 10
```

it shows me the browser windows for 10 seconds but it is useless if I can go to any page, any ideas about what is going wrong?

Comment: Please add `$DEBUG = true` after the require line. Rerun and post the output. Might be easiest to paste it into pastebin or gist and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid closing browser, you need to include this code now

```
require 'watir'
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_options: {detach: true})
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
b.goto('www.example.com')
```

Try this, it works fine.

Comment: I copy and paste exactly your code but I still get the same error, the only difference is that now the browser doesnt close, but it doesnt go to the page that I specify in the argument.

Comment: Can you try to with some other website like 'www.google.com'? because I am not getting any error.

Comment: actually the page that I am trying to got to is google

Comment: nope, it return the same error that at the beginning

Comment: Okay, I don't know, It's running fine for me without any problem.